# set different values for an element depending on whether it contains text or not

Tags: xpath

I need to make small xpath adjustments from time to time for a set of layouts for my boss. My knowledge in Xpath is very limited, so forgive me if I can't describe everything in a comprehensive manner.

My problem:

I want to set different values for the line height of an element "table-title" depending on whether the element "table-title" contains any text or not. I can't check whether or not the element "table-title" is completely empty because it may contain an element "meta-ref", even when there is no following text.

I work with {ctrl:If(x,'y','z')} to set the values based on whether the condition is met or not, the condition being "x" and the values being "y" if met and "z" if not met. This is what I've tried:
`{ctrl:If(table-title[contains(text(),'')],'0.1%','100%')}`

The code I am working with has no text after `</meta-ref>`. But to show where the text would appear, I added it here.

```
<table-container>
    <table-title>
        <meta-ref @name="Layoutmarker>'TableGrid'</meta-ref>This is a table title text.
    </table-title>
</table-container>
```

I want the line height to be 0.1% when there is no text in the element "table-title" and 100% when there is.
I expect the result to be `0.1%` but it is actually `100%`, even though there is no text.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for opening up this issue. I've been getting desperate because I couldn't find the solution for several days, but here it is:

`{ctrl:If(self::table-title[not(text())],'0.1%','100%')}`

This successfully reduces the line height to 0.1% when the table-title doesn't contain any text.